# How to initialize two std::arrays in constructor initializer list when second depends on first

Tags: c++, constructor, stdarray

Of the various ways to initialize `std::array` class members in the constructor initializer list, I found the variadic parameter pack to work best.

However, how can I initialize a second `std::array` member which depends on the first?

The example here is a `struct polygon` which takes a variadic parameter pack of `Vector2` vertices. From those vertices we also construct the lines. These lines store the vertices again (references or pointers seem unnecessary given the typical 16byte size of a Vector2) in pairs of `line.start` and `line.end` and also pre-compute the Length and normal vector of the line for performance.

Note: I don't want to use two `std::vector`s - that's what the working code has already.

Is there a way to move the logic from the constructor body to the constructor initializer list for this case?

```cpp
template <unsigned N, typename Number = double>
struct polygon {

    std::array<Vector2<Number>, N> vertices;
    std::array<Line<Number>, N>    lines; // this is calling Line's default constructor: TOO EARLY

    template <typename... Pack>
    polygon(Pack... vs)
        : vertices{vs...} /* , lines{ .... ??? } this is where we need to construct / initialize lines */ {
        static_assert(sizeof...(vs) == N, "incorrect number of vertices passed");
        for (auto i = 0UL; i != vertices.size(); ++i) {
            // this is calling Line's copy assignment operator: TOO LATE
            lines[i] = Line(vertices[i], vertices[(i + 1) % vertices.size()]);
        }
    }
// ...
}

using Vec2  = Vector2<double>;

using triangle      = polygon<3>;
using quadrilateral = polygon<4>;
using pentagon      = polygon<5>;

int main() {

    auto tri = triangle(Vec2{1, 2}, Vec2{3, 4}, Vec2{4, 5});
    std::cout << tri << "\n";
    // this would be even nicer, but doesn't work: "substitution failure: deduced incomplete pack"
    // auto tri = triangle({1, 2}, {3, 4}, {4, 5});

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put patterns in front of a `...`, not just the pack. However, this requires a suitable pack. In this case, a useful pack would be the indices, so you can make a helper for that:

```
template<std::size_t... Is>
auto make_lines(std::index_sequence<Is...>) {
    return std::array<Line<Number>, N>{
        Line(vertices[Is], vertices[(Is + 1) % vertices.size()])...
    };
}
```

`std::index_sequence` is simply a standard holder type for a bunch of `std::size_t`s, no behaviour of its own.

Then you create the pack when calling it:

```
polygon(Pack... vs)
    : vertices{vs...},
      lines(make_lines(std::index_sequence_for<Pack...>{})) { ... }
```

`std::index_sequence_for` takes the elements of `Pack` and creates a sequence `0, 1, 2, ..., N-1`, one per element received. That is, it's a sequence from 0 to `sizeof...(Pack) - 1`, perfect for indices.

Comment: Yeah, that's the kind of "magic" I was dreaming of. Nice one. Will try it now.

Comment: Could a similar approach help with the calling code API in main? See comment there (I updated the question just before your answer came through).

Comment: The `make_lines` part works like a charm. Thank you. have accepted your answer. I tried to write a `make_vertices` (so we don't have to put `Vec2{}` for every vertex in calling code) but I couldn't make it work...

Comment: @OliverSchönrock, I'm almost sure you can reduce the boilerplate by taking the array directly or at the least, making a `make_polygon<triangle>(...)` style helper, but I don't know if I'm in the right headspace for it. It would be very nice if we had homogenous packs in the language for this. The crux is that `{1,2}` doesn't have a type, so it can't be used to deduce a type.

Comment: Why is it `template<std::size_t... Is>` (mentioning a concrete typename) compared with `template <typename... Pack>`? Is that because the former is a "Pack of NTTPs"?

Comment: @OliverSchönrock, Yes, `template<std::size_t...> struct foo;` can be filled with `foo<1, 5, 2>` for example. Update on the calling code, you can [make it work](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/e6hGojaq5), but this is rather messy and I hope I'm just missing something obvious that someone else will point out. The slight variation on that is to have `polygon` take a `std::array` directly and use `std::make_index_sequence` instead of `std::index_sequence_for`, which gets rid of the `std::apply`. The really unfortunate thing is that this uses a C array for deduction purposes and then copies that.

Comment: Thank you. I think I need to read more of this: http://www.tmplbook.com/ ! I do have a copy ;-)

Comment: @OliverSchönrock, It's unfortunate you ran into the deduction-from-braces problem so early, but yeah, having a few common template tricks under your belt can be very handy. For completeness, I'll mention that the index sequence trick is often more handy when combined with a lambda, but the constructor initializer list isn't a great place for lambdas in general. You can see an example [in this post](https://vittorioromeo.info/index/blog/cpp20_lambdas_compiletime_for.html), specifically the `for_range` implementation.